# How to play half notes with three (32nds) beams?

Tags: notation

In an arrangement of a piece of [Tchaikovsky's *Swan Lake* <sup>(link to imslp.org)</sup>](https://imslp.org/wiki/Swan_Lake_(ballet)%2C_Op.20_(Tchaikovsky%2C_Pyotr)#Sc.C3.A8ne._Moderato_.28Act_2_No.10.29) for flute and piano I found following notation of four half notes (and later two full notes) but with 32nds beams that confuses me - how is this supposed to be played?

If it was only two half notes I would have expected that it is just a "lazy" notation of filling the (4/4) bar with 32nds, but here we have four of them which doesn't seem to match the time signature. If it is intended that way, how is it supposed to be played? Or is it maybe a typo?

[image]